# How can I convince my new employer to hire me w/o Releiving letter from one of the previous employer?

Tags: job-change, human-resources, relieving-letter

I have 8 years of work experience and I worked in 3 companies. Now I got an offer from a new MNC but I don't have relieving and experience letter from 2nd employer where I worked for 13 months.

The reason for this was not serving 90 days notice period because the next Company was not ready to wait for more than 30 days and was fine with hiring me on the basis of resignation mail only, so I left my 2nd employer giving 9 days notice. I have my salary slip and Resignation mail (without acceptance).

Now the new Company I am looking forward to join might ask Relieving  and experience letter for 2nd employer. I requested head HR of my 2nd employer to settle my account and issue my docs but he denied.

How can I convince hr of new org to hire me. I can submit Relieving of my 1st and 3rd company immediately. What are the alternatives??

Comment: I am trying to get it from my previous employer. While resigning from my 2nd employer my present employer was not ready to wait for more than 30 days and was ready to buyout remaining notice period. So I dont have any option but to join my current org at that time. Is this a good explaination??

Answer (score 3):

Leaving without respecting the notice period of 90 days basically burned bridges with your second employer. If you don't made their life easy upon leaving you cannot expect them to make yours easy now.

This also hints that you are not able to keep your word, which is generally a red flag.

You cannot really convince a company to skip certain steps in the hiring process that they deem necessary, as doing so would just smell too fishy and add another big red flag on you.

Your best option is being honest: explain them why you cannot give them the documents they ask for, and possibly provide a good explanation on why you trashed the 90 days notice period. You want to make sure they trust your ability to stick to your word.

Comment: I am trying to get it from my previous employer. While resigning from my 2nd employer my present employer was not ready to wait for more than 30 days and was ready to buyout remaining notice period. So I dont have any option but to join my current org at that time. Is this a good explaination??

Comment: Did they get a monetary compensation for letting you go earlier or not?

Comment: May be yes because my full and final and PF is not settled by them.